# Is there any way to detect whether a web api has updated?

Tags: security

There’s a lot of urls to scan for web security. I want to do a re-scan if the web api behind a url has updated. Is there any way to detect it?

My current solution is  detecting it by detecting the change of page content, with calculating the simhash and Hamming distance. But the change of a web api may not affect its response.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no general solution to query from the client side wether an API running on the server has been updated.

If such a method existed, it would lead to any number of security issues.

You may want to request a list of updated APIs from the developer.